# Tablix width is decresing in printout

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I have 1 tablix in my report of 24.8cm width, i given a printout of this report, but in printout my tablix width converted into 23.8cm.
pls tell me why this is happening?

Comment: This is probably due to margin just as explained by Ocean's answer. Check also your printer set-up it might be the culprit and click Print Layout before exporting to see the actual print-out.

Answer (score 2):

This might have something to do with your `PageSize` and the `Margins`. It's even possible that the table's border-width are causing it to be only just too wide to fit.
If there is not enough horizontal space on the page to place the entire table, the table will shrink in width.

> Max `Table's width` = `Page's width` - (`Margin-Left` + `Margin-Right`)

So I suggest you try one of the following:

- Reduce the size of the  `Left-` or `Right-Margin` property.
- Increase the `Width` of the `PageSize` property.